# How to fix CORS error when posting form from client to AWS API gateway function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, cors, serverless-framework

I have a contact form on my front end react application that I want to post to an Lambda function that is behind a API Gateway which in turn has a custom domain on top of it.

My front end runs on domain `dev.example.com:3000` 
My API Gateway is on `contact.example.com`

Further more, I have created my Lambda function with serverless and in my YAML file, have enabled CORS as so:

```
# serverless.yml

service: contact-form-api

custom:
  secrets: ${file(secrets.json)}

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  stage: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
  region: us-east-1
  environment: 
    NODE_ENV: ${self:custom.secrets.NODE_ENV}
    EMAIL: ${self:custom.secrets.EMAIL}
    DOMAIN: ${self:custom.secrets.DOMAIN}
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - "ses:SendEmail"
      Resource: "*"

functions:
  send:
    handler: handler.send
    events:
      - http:
          path: email/send
          method: post
          cors: true
```

I am using AXIOS to make my post request which happens client side:

```
const data = await axios.post(
    "https://contact.example.com/email/send",
    formData,
    {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }
)
```

And the error I get is:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://contact.example.com/email/send' from origin 'http://dev.example.com:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains the invalid value 'example.com'.

I would have thought having the front end and API on the same domain would get around any cors errors (although I am spoofing `dev.example.com`) locally in order to test). I would also think the cors setting in my YAML file would get around it.

Anybody know why I might still be getting this CORS error?

Edit: Showing handler code that runs in Lambda function
    // handler.js

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk')
const ses = new aws.SES()
const myEmail = process.env.EMAIL
const myDomain = process.env.DOMAIN

function generateResponse (code, payload) {
  return {
    statusCode: code,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-requested-with',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(payload)
  }
}

function generateError (code, err) {
  console.log(err)
  return {
    statusCode: code,
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'x-requested-with',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(err.message)
  }
}

function generateEmailParams (body) {
  const { email, name, content } = JSON.parse(body)
  console.log(email, name, content)
  if (!(email && name && content)) {
    throw new Error('Missing parameters! Make sure to add parameters \'email\', \'name\', \'content\'.')
  }

  return {
    Source: myEmail,
    Destination: { ToAddresses: [myEmail] },
    ReplyToAddresses: [email],
    Message: {
      Body: {
        Text: {
          Charset: 'UTF-8',
          Data: `Message sent from email ${email} by ${name} \nContent: ${content}`
        }
      },
      Subject: {
        Charset: 'UTF-8',
        Data: `You received a message from ${myDomain}!`
      }
    }
  }
}

module.exports.send = async (event) => {
  try {
    const emailParams = generateEmailParams(event.body)
    const data = await ses.sendEmail(emailParams).promise()
    return generateResponse(200, data)
  } catch (err) {
    return generateError(500, err)
  }
}
```

Comment: because the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header should either have the value `*` or `http://dev.example.com:3000` ... i.e. protocol and port need to match the origin

Comment: Do you mean the header in Axios post request?

Comment: sorry, I thought it was obvious I was talking about the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header -

Comment: I just wanted to double check as I did try your suggestion but to no avail. I tried setting both `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "dev.example.com:3000"` and `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"` but still getting the same CORS error

Comment: a) I said `http://dev.example.com:3000` not `dev.example.com:3000` and b) I can't see anywhere you are doing any of that, so perhaps you are doing it wrong (check in the browser to see what headers you are actually getting from the server)

Comment: c) can you show how you're setting the various headers? all I see is `cors: true` - nothing about the headers themselves

Comment: @JaromandaX I have uploaded my handler.js file that runs in the Lambda function. It previously had `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` set to `contact.example.com` but have now made it a wildcard which now makes it work. Thanks for your help. If you'd like to post an answer, I'll mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

You should add an HTTP request header as 'Content-type':

[image]

Now, go to Integration requests, and change the mapping template as follows:

[image]

Hope, it helps. and don't forgot to deploy the API before testing.